# How do I prove a half open interval is a sigma algebra?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I was reading the lecture notes about probability and random processes, [Lecture Notes](https://www.math.kth.se/matstat/gru/sf2940/lectnotemat5.pdf), then I'm stucked here:

> Example 1.3.6 Let $\Omega = \mathbb R$ and suppose that we have a sigma field A such that all intervals of the form:

> $[ 1, 2 - 1/n) \in \mathcal{A}$

So, I would like to know how to prove that interval is a $\sigma$ algebra?

1. $\Omega \in \mathcal{A}$
2. If $A \in \mathcal{A}$, then $A^{c} \in \mathcal{A}$
3. If $A_{n} \in \mathcal{A}$ for each $n$ in a countable collection $(A_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$, then $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \in \mathcal{A}$.

I know from the lecture note that:

$[1, 2) \in \mathcal{A}$, since $\lim_{n\to\infty} [1, 2 - 1/n)$

I think its prove statement 3. Am I right?

But I don't know how to prove statements 1 and 2.

Comment: An interval is never a $\sigma$-algebra. The $\sigma$-algebra you are considering __contains__ interval, but is not an interval itself! And no, the fact you cite does not prove 3., because you have to take any countable union and prove that the limit is in $\mathcal{A}$. To be more precise, I do not even see, why you would like to prove that it is a $\sigma$-algebra: it has been defined to be one...?

Comment: If you are trying to show $[1,2)\in \mathcal A$ then take the countable union over $n$ of the intervals $[ 1, 2 - 1/n)$.

Comment: Hi @MushuNrek, maybe it is my misunderstanding. They said we have a $\sigma$-algebra such that all intervals are the form: $[1, 2 - 1/n) \in \mathcal{A}$. And about the $\emptyset$ and the complement of the interval? I didn't get it.

Comment: Yes, the $\sigma$-algebra contains all these intervals. But to be a $\sigma$-algebra, it must contain even more sets. And in the exercise, they take any $\sigma$-algebra which does at least contain those intervals. (Later on, you will see that it is very common, to define a $\sigma$-algebra by enumerating the "important" sets it contains. But naturally, other sets will also be part of it.)

Comment: The above comments already say this but I wanted to make it explicit: You use the fact that 3 is true to prove $[1,2) \in \mathcal{A}$.  The other direction does not make sense: You cannot use the fact that $[1,2) \in \mathcal{A}$ to "prove" 3. (Mushu's first comment gives 2 separate reasons why it does not make sense).

Comment: Thank you guys! @MushuNrek gave me an insight. Thanks.